# Remove black color view from MFSideMenuController (Right Side)

Tags: ios, iphone

I have used MFSideMenu for displaying my menu items . But i dont know why it is showing me black line at the end .

How to remove the black part .

Here is the image what is appearing at the end

[image]

I have used https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu to integrate MFSideMenu.

This is my code for Sidemen

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.view.backgroundColor = CustomPinkColor;
MenuArray =[NSArray   arrayWithObjects:@"Knects",@"Settings",@"Share",@"About",nil];
//tableView.backgroundColor = CustomPinkColor;
tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
[tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

}

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:   (NSInteger)section
 {
return MenuArray.count;
  }

  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.backgroundColor=CustomPinkColor;
    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [MenuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
  }

  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
return 40;
 }

   - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
UIView *colorView = [[UIView alloc]init];
colorView.backgroundColor = CustomPinkColor;
return colorView;
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an autolayout issue, this way you can fix this:

**Step 1:** Add this method to MFSideMenuContainerViewController controller

```
   - (void)layoutContraintsforLeftView:(UIView*)view adjestToContainer:(UIView*)container {
    if(!view) {
        return;
    }

    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [container addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:container
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];

    [container addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:container
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];

    [container addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:container
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0]];

    [container addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:container
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];
    [view layoutIfNeeded];
}



- (void)layoutContraintsForRightView:(UIView*)view adjestToContainer:(UIView*)container {
    if(!view) {
        return;
    }

    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [container addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:container
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];

    [container addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:container
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:50.0]];

    [container addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:container
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];

    [container addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:container
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:0.0]];
    [view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

**Step 2:** Replace method `- (void)setupMenuContainerView)` with this

```
    - (void)setupMenuContainerView {
    if(self.menuContainerView.superview) return;

    self.menuContainerView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    self.menuContainerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    [self.view insertSubview:menuContainerView atIndex:0];
    [self layoutContraintsforLeftView:menuContainerView adjestToContainer:self.view];


    if(self.leftMenuViewController && !self.leftMenuViewController.view.superview) {
        [self.menuContainerView addSubview:self.leftMenuViewController.view];
        [self layoutContraintsforLeftView:self.leftMenuViewController.view adjestToContainer:menuContainerView];
    }

    if(self.rightMenuViewController && !self.rightMenuViewController.view.superview) {
        [self.menuContainerView addSubview:self.rightMenuViewController.view];
        [self layoutContraintsForRightView:self.rightMenuViewController.view adjestToContainer:menuContainerView];
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** It's now done; run your code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have tested in this codebase https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu. It is working in there..

Comment: Are you using autolayout in list view?

Comment: No i have not used autolayout

Comment: If possible can you share your piece of code to understand what is issue?

Comment: Hi Ammy .. Can you add constraint for your table view like leading 0, trailing 0 , top 0 and bottom 0 .. may this help you

Comment: Hi ammy your issue was get resolved .. that you were seeing black on the bottom.. Can you please accept it.. other person can get solution.

Comment: ya sure , but can you see my code and update . As i have no idea now what to do. ?

Comment: Sure Ammy..I am looking in to it.. please accept my answer, so more people get to know solution .

Comment: Ok sure @sachin , Please see what i can do ..? TEXTS are not visible after using your code .

Comment: I can't accept this answer , As This code hides my UITABLEVIEW TEXT LABELS @sachin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94163/discussion-between-ammy-and-sachin).

Comment: It works only for the left hand side ,  On right is makes the cell texxt invisible @Sachin

Comment: @Ammy Got solution of your problem come to chat .